# .isEqualTo vs .equals in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, equals, difference

I have to write an unit test in java, and was wondering what is the difference between .isEqualTo and .equals.

Here is an example of my code:

```
mockLog.message(0).header(SOURCE_HEADER).isEqualTo("String");
```

VS

```
mockLog.message(0).header(SOURCE_HEADER).equals("String");
```

It seems that both is giving me the right information, but my colleague and I was wondering what's the difference between them.

Comment: What type does `header` have?

Comment: I suppose the `isEqualTo` method comes either with Hamcrest, JUnit or AssertJ whereas the `equals` method is standard java method

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. More specifically: you seem to call methods that exist on **your** classes --- in other words - what is *header()* supposed to return?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using something like AssertJ, equals() will just return false but isEqualsTo() will throw an exception.